# Mock alias states for UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a number of pages/url that all use the same parent state/template:

```
/orders/list
/orders/create
/products/list
/products/create
```

Right now I have 2 dummy states/routes ( /products and  /orders)that are solely there to create parent states for the other substates - a) I don't them and b) I am duplicating them in order to achieve the desired URLs.

```
.state('orders', {
      url: "/orders",
      templateUrl: "/partials/common/main"
    })
    .state('products', {
      url: "/products",
      templateUrl: "/partials/common/main"
    })
    .state('orders.list', {
      url: "/view",
      templateUrl: "/partials/orders/view"
    })
    .state('orders.create', {
      url: "/create",
      templateUrl: "/partials/orders/edit"
    })
    .state('products.list', {
      url: "/view",
      templateUrl: "/partials/products/view"
    })
    .state('products.create', {
      url: "/create",
      templateUrl: "/partials/products/edit"
    })
```

Is there some functionality that I can use to clean this up? At the very least have only one main state - I looked around for aliases but could not find anything.

Something such as:

```
.state('main', {
  url: "/[orders|products]",  // some kind of url match
  templateUrl: "/partials/common/main"
})
```

Note that /partials/common/main contains an inner ui-view that is used by all orders/... and products/... and this view is the same in the above 2 main routes (in reality I have ~10 of the same "placeholder" routes)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the unused states `abstract: true`, which means they simply act as dummies. However, the dummy routes require a template like `<div ui-view=""></div>` or something along those lines, so that the child templates know where to load.

If you do no controller logic with these abstract routes, then you can always leave them out, and simply create your child routes `orders.list` and `orders.create` without actually creating an `orders` state. Depends on your requirements.

Comment: Well orders.list, etc need to load in an inner ui-view present in `/partials/common/main` so is there a way to leave out the parent routes and somehow specify this? Or is running multiple abstract parent states the only way?

Comment: Yeah, I tend to have an abstract state for every common reusable parent view. It usually makes sense though, because then you have common controllers for each child, so you can put a lot of common logic there as well.